# Using Grails Acegi Plugin when a User domains "enabled" field is set to false. The user can still login

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, spring-security

Is the disabling of users natively supported by the Acegi Grails plugin?

From the Documentation it appears to support the "enabled" field..
But after setting the Users "enabled" field to false, the user can still login and no "user is disabled" exception is thrown ( although there appears to be a catch for a user disabled exception in the default logincontroller)...

If this functionality is supported are there any other changes needed other than setting the users "enabled" field to false?

Guessing that this may not be supported, i have added a check to the login controller to check if a user is enabled when the user is logged in and sending them back to the login screen with a disabled message...

```
    def index = {
   if (isLoggedIn()) {
    def dc = authenticateService.principal().domainClass
        def user = User.get( dc.id )
        if (!user.enabled){
            session.invalidate()
            flash.message = "User '"+user.username+"' is disabled."
            redirect action: auth, params: params
        }else{
            setLoginDate()
            redirect uri: '/home/'
        }
    }
```

However, this only work when I access the login page directly. When I try to login after entering a url (eg */user/list) from within the application; the user logs in and is taken url without calling my check in the logincontroller...

Comment: `user.enabled == 0` will never be true - it's a boolean, so it should be `if (!user.enabled) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a filter instead.  I'm not sure the index closure is called unless you indeed hit the base URI for that controller.

http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/single.html#6.6%20Filters